# What standard must a component/ device comply with to be industrial grade?

Tags: standard, industrial

I am looking at an iot device that claims to be industrial grade.

It meets standards such as UL60950-1 and has an operating temperature -40 --> 85C so looks good but is that enough?

Exactly what standards must a device comply with to be industrial grade?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the device or at least the manufacturer and part number? As far as I know, some parts are specified to work over the industrial temperature range. I have not heard the terminology "industrial grade." I have just heard the term "industrial temperature range."

Comment: The device is here: https://www.multitech.com/brands/multiconnect-rcell-100-series Industrial grade is being bandied about but it only says -- industrial router.  If there is no such thing as industrial grade that's fine. just need to know.  The question is not about the device as I have to review about 8 different types.

Answer (score 3):

'Industrial Grade' is not really a thing.

'Industrial Temperature Range' is -40°C to +85°C.

UL60950-1 may be enough for your application, or it may not. Do you have a target reliability level that your product has to meet?

Simply using qualified components in your design is not enough, if you use them in ways that are not reliable. When I was designing in industry, we had a blanket derating policy that used resistors to only 50% of their rated power, capacitors to only 70% of their rated voltage.  If you use this industrial component to 100% of its ratings, or 110%, then it may not give you the reliability you hope for.

Answer (score 1):

> Exactly what standards must a device comply with to be industrial grade?

Standards exist to provide some design specification in accordance to the known operating environment.

Do you know where your IOT device will be installed and consider requirements such as:

- Thermal limits
- Mechanical/Vibration
- Electrical
- Ageing
- Stress
- Intrinsic fault safety

Those are the sort of questions you need to ask , industrial grade is not a criterion for that.

You need to design accordingly.